# Creating ion-search bar using ionic not using ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I created the application using  as per below coding, I want to handle the list view with ionic search bar as per below image. Is it possible, If so suggest me some ideas or else code blog It would be helpful for me.

Note : As per below code, Searching was worked well but if the search happened its shows the text with matched list and even not matched list with an empty cell. So I want to handle the search like second snap mentioned below.

> sample.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Call Lists">
<ion-content class="customListView" has-header="true">

<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
<input type="search" placeholder=" Search" ng-model="searchValue"
style="width:100%; padding-left:11px;" />
</div>

<ion-list>

<ion-item class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in callItems.objects"  ng-click="doTask()" can-swipe="true">

<ion-option-button class="button-positive"
ng-click="doEdit()">
<i class="ion-more"></i>
</ion-option-button>

<img src="img/men.png">
<i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>

<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.Fields | filter:searchValue">

<h3>  {{value.Value}}</h3>

</div>

</ion-item>

</ion-list>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

> Output :

[image: Snap - 1]

> I Want to do like below :

[image: Snap - 2]

Answer (score 0):

While adding the below line empty cell issues got fixed.

```
<ion-item class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in callItems.objects | filter:searchValue"  ng-click="doTask()" can-swipe="true">
```

> Instead of

```
<ion-item class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in callItems.objects "  ng-click="doTask()" can-swipe="true">
```

Thing is I've given two ng-repeat as per my scenarios, So I've to set search filter for both.

> If anyone having the ideas regarding the search activity as per mentioned in the second snap, Share me your ideas or code blog It would be helpful for me.